# How can I invalidate cache the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a very specific cache situation. We use several solutions for caching and I wonder what is the best solution to invalidate the cache on a user action.

The cache is like so

- First layer: CDN caches the full page as HTML for logged-out users
- Second layer: full page cache in memcached for logged-out users
  the reason I have the second layer is to respond to edges, sometimes not all edges are cached, so I want to "answer" the edge from cache as well.
- Third layer: cache HTML partials and database data for logged-in users.

My problem is that my invalidation process is very much based on the third layer right now, and I don't answer the second and first layer well enough.

My question is: what is the best way to invalidate the cache on the full URL from a cache key that has absolutely no coupling with the URL? For example, if I have a trip plan, inside the trip plan there are comments, I want to invalidate the full page trip plan URL when a user comments with a new comment.

Comment model has no URL, and the "parent" also doesn't have the URL, the same comment will also apear in the city page, so it's completely a reusable object and partial.

Answer (score 3):

I read some blogposts by David Heinemeier Hansson on the 37signals [blog](http://37signals.com/svn).

Their take on the problem is to cache all the different objects on the page and then use CSS and JS to customize the view.

- In the [first post](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3112-how-basecamp-next-got-to-be-so-damn-fast-without-using-much-client-side-ui) DHH goes through the technology they used to make the new interface for Basecamp to be so damn fast.
- In the [second post](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) he goes through how key-based expiration works.

It may not solve your problems but with the description you gave i think it might at least give you some tips.

Comment: This is actually a very good solution and changed the way I think about caching. If the guy who started this thread hasn't read these posts yet, he should. It sounds like exactly what he needs (invalidate a whole page if something inside changes).